# add files to solr with C#

Tags: c#, solr

i have XML files that I want to index to solr. is there a C# code to do it without building the whole document all over again as a .net class?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [SolrNet](https://code.google.com/p/solrnet) and follow the *fully loose mapping* steps outlined in the [Mapping](https://code.google.com/p/solrnet/wiki/Mapping) details. This would allow you to create a document by just using a `Dictionary<string, object>` in place of a class mapped to your index document.

Answer (score 1):

If you are flexible enough you can check Solr [DataImportHandler](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler)(DIH) which will allow you to [index xml file](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#Usage_with_XML.2BAC8-HTTP_Datasource) directly without any Interaction with C# code.